# Edittext not reading string starting with comma

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have made an activity in my Android app containing a edittext field. Everything works fine except that this edittext is not reading string starting with comma. 
Need help from coding world :p

Comment: post your code please

Comment: Show your code so we can do something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank u everyone . it was all my fault. Edittext was working fine . Actually, I was converting the  edittext string  into a json object along with 2 other string fields . after this I converted this  json obj into a string which was sent to gcm server and in the receiving device I was converting this string into hasmap using seperator as comma (culprit).
I solved it by replacing the , with 'comma' on sender side .and replaced all the entries with comma to ' , ' on receiver side.

Answer (score 2):

Well before you start i recommend you to try another device.

So here is a simple example of getting a string starting with comma.

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v)
    {
       String commastring = (String) edit.getText().toString();
    } 
});
//show commastring
```

Also you can check it

```
if(commastring.contains(","){
//true
}
```

That should works

Comment: just a smart ass comments: use `String.valueOf(edit.getText());` instead of  `(String) edit.getText().toString()`.. AND use `if(commastring.startsWith(",")) ` instead of `if(commastring.contains(","))` :)

Comment: Thank you guys.. I solved it.. The problem was in my code . edittext was working fine..

Comment: Awesome!
if you want you can post or accept the answer you want